# C# memory leak after inputing and rotating image Bitmap from USB camera

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, bitmap

I initiate image frame download from USB camera to C# windows app:
(Uses Accord's (ie. AForge) VideoCaptureDevice)

```
// Automatically start inputing each frame from camera:
var videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
// Select physical USB camera:                 http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Video_DirectShow_VideoCaptureDevice.htm
videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice( videoDevices[0].MonikerString, pixelFormat_for_ExhaustiveTemplateMatching);
// Select event handlers:
videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( EVENT_camera_frame ); //http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Video_NewFrameEventArgs.htm

// Start slurpin up them camera frames:
videoSource.Start();
```

Then, I process each event that contains the next image frame from camera:

```
    private static void EVENT_camera_frame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs camera_frame_event)
    {
        if( latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap != null )
        {
            latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Dispose();
        }

        // Allocate camera Bitmap buffer:
        camera_buffer_Bitmap = new Bitmap( 
        // ..rotate and copy raw camera frame image bitmap from camera_frame_Bitmap to camera_buffer_Bitmap: 
        image_rotator_RotateBilinear.Apply(   camera_frame_Bitmap ));       ///////////  2ND BITMAP BUFFER   /////////////

        // Init a Bitmap for size of frame from camera and for conversion from camera native pixel format to comparison compatible format Format24bppRgb:
        latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap = new Bitmap(    camera_frame_Bitmap.Width, 
                                                camera_frame_Bitmap.Height,
                                                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // From rotated, camera format image bitmap in camera_frame_Bitmap, convert to Format24bppRgb and copy to latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap:
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage( latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap))
        {
            gr.DrawImage( camera_buffer_Bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                                                latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Width,
                                                                latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Height));

            camera_buffer_Bitmap.Dispose();
            // Draw crop rectangle in Live Camera View:
            using( Graphics live_image_Graphics = Graphics.FromImage( latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap ) )
            {
                live_image_Graphics.DrawRectangle( crop_pen, crop_display_rectangle );   /////////////   DRAW CROPPING RECTANGLE   /////////////
            }
            // Show crop rectangle in PictureBox of Live Camera View:
            control_panel.show_camera_crosshairs();    
        } 
camera_frame_Bitmap.Dispose();   // I just tried this, but didn't fix the leak.
    }
```

Then, I do .BeginInvoke to 'schedule' UI thread to update PictureBox:

```
public  void show_camera_crosshairs()
{
    // Show crosshairs, if requested in camera view:

    // Create pen.
    Pen crosshairs_pen = new Pen(Color.White, 1 );

    int width = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Width;
    int height = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Height;

    int top_y = height - 1;
    int bottom_y = 0;
    int left_x = 0;
    int right_x = width - 1;

    // Create points that define line.
    Point crosshair_point_top = new Point( width / 2, top_y );
    Point crosshair_point_bottom = new Point( width / 2, bottom_y );
    Point crosshair_point_left = new Point( 0, height / 2 );
    Point crosshair_point_right = new Point( width-1, height / 2 );

    float[] dashValues = { 4, 2 };
    crosshairs_pen.DashPattern = dashValues;
    // Verticle crosshair:
    Graphics live_image_Graphics = Graphics.FromImage( Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap );
    live_image_Graphics.DrawLine( crosshairs_pen, crosshair_point_top, crosshair_point_bottom );

    // Horizontal crosshair:
    live_image_Graphics.DrawLine( crosshairs_pen,  crosshair_point_left, crosshair_point_right );
    live_image_Graphics.Dispose();

    // Display latest frame from camera:
    Common.dbg("","","BeginInvoke: update_PictureBox");
    PictureBox_live_camera.BeginInvoke( new update_PictureBox_Delegate( update_PictureBox ));
}
```

And, finally, I have UI thread update PictureBox...

```
public delegate void update_PictureBox_Delegate(  );

public  void update_PictureBox()
{
    Common.dbg("","","");
    Computer_Vision_API.computer_vision_resource.WaitOne();
    Common.dbg("","","computer_vision_resource");
    PictureBox_live_camera.Image = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap;
    PictureBox_live_camera.BackgroundImage = Computer_Vision_API.latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap;
    Computer_Vision_API.computer_vision_resource.ReleaseMutex();           // release use of computer vision Bitmap buffers, etc.
}
```

Here's a look at the memory leak...
[image]

U P D A T E :
I narrowed the cause of the memory leak down to this line:

```
image_rotator_RotateBilinear.Apply(   camera_frame_Bitmap ));       ///////////  2ND BITMAP BUFFER   /////////////
```

Comment below suggests sawtooth pattern doesn't infer a memory leak at all -- just my misassumption.  Here is latest memory pattern...
[image]

Comment: Where are you cleaning up your previous bitmaps? `Bitmap` is disposable, you need to get rid of previous images when you create a new one.

Comment: At the lines with ...    latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Dispose();
   and   camera_buffer_Bitmap.Dispose();

Comment: Ok, maybe I missed those. Why do you call your screenshot a memory leak? It seems that memory goes up for a bit and is reclaimed, in cycles. Does it actually keep increasing over time? (Hard to tell the peaks from the screenshot.)

Comment: xxbbcc:  So, that's just a garbage collection pattern, then?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment until now. Yes, based on your screenshot, it just seems a GC pattern. If the peaks keep going higher and higher over time, that would indicate a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not in code.
It was my misunderstanding of the memory pattern shown by Diag Tool (diagram above).  Though memory usage increases over several of the event callbacks, the intelligent garbage collector doesn't auto dispose every callback.

Thanks to xxbbcc's illuminating comment.